# embedding python in c++

Tags: c++, python

I created a VCL Application in c++, borland. In my project there is a file where I have implemented embedded python in the methods defined in the same(my application contains a button which calls the method in which embedded python is implemented). when I compile, my build is successful. but when I run my application, and click on the button it shows the run time error : "Access violation at address 1E091375 in module 'PYTHON25.DLL'. Read of address 00000004" . please help.
I have never used Python before.
my program:

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


#include "Python.h"

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"
#pragma link "python25_bcpp.lib"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma package(smart_init)

bool callHelloWorld(int intVal)
{
    char fName[] = "Hello"; //file name
    char cFunc[] = "hello"; //method name

    char *pfName, *pcFunc;

    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc ;

    pfName = fName;
    pcFunc = cFunc;

    Py_Initialize();

    pName = PyString_FromString(pfName);

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, pcFunc);

    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
    } else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }


    // Py_DECREF(pModule);
    // Py_DECREF(pName);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I seem to remember that Borland C++ uses a different calling convention (fastcall?).  Is your python.dll compiled using the same compiler?

Comment: the python25.dll was in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. I didnt compile it.

Comment: I dont know if this would help or not, but I think you are missing some of the python files. I remember getting the same error when trying to compile my program on a different machine. But in my case I was using an MFC program and I was accessing my MFC DLL using the python script. Probably try reinstalling python.

Comment: I have placed all the files like .h ,lib and .dll in the source folder. I think the issue is with loading the module Hello.py. Can you please suggest how should i load the module successfully.

Comment: It won't be calling convention since `python.h` will specify cdecl. To help us can you tell us which line fails.

Comment: [BCC32 Error] python25.dll(1): E2141 Declaration syntax error
Full parser context
Unit2.cpp(19): #include python25.dll
=========================
[BCC32 Error] python25.dll(3): E2206 Illegal character '$' (0x24)
Full parser context
Unit2.cpp(19): #include python25.dll
==========================
[BCC32 Error] python25.dll(4): E2206 Illegal character '?' (0xe)
Full parser context
Unit2.cpp(19): #include python25.dll
[BCC32 Error] python25.dll(1): E2206 Illegal character '' (0x0)

Comment: That looks like a compiler error. You said before you had a runtime AV.

Comment: "Access violation at address 1E091375 in module 'PYTHON25.DLL'. Read of address 00000004". i am getting this runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return values of `PyImport_Import` (is the module in the search path?) and `PyDict_GetItemString`.

If that doesn't help put some trace messages in your app to see where it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Just delete **Py_Finalize()**

I read in another site that **Py_Finalize** has some problems in specific cases such as threading.

Comment: Same issue and same solution after all those years. 
Use Py_FinalizeEx for Python 3.